# Classify Excel Filter

Tags: excel

My Excels filters are not showing values as asc neither desc.

As we can see the First column filter is:

```
0
1
10
11
12
```

And should be:

```
0
1
2
3
...
```

The Second Column is:

```
01/07/2019
01/08/2019
02/07/2019
02/08/2019
```

And should be:

```
01/07/2019
02/07/2019
01/08/2019
02/08/2019
```

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: It shows values in order, but it treats (i.e. sorts) them as strings.

Comment: But columns types are set as Number and Date....

Comment: The types do not help if the values were put in as text in the first place. If the numbers are left-oriented, they are treated as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be fixed as long as your values are text values (therefore it says "Filtros de Texto"). If you transfer the values in numbers or dates it will be fine. Whith dates, you will even get the selection of certain months and years!

You can transfer the values by

- editing every single value (F2 - Enter - F2 - Enter - ...)
- taking them to another column with the Function  `VALUE(A2)`
- specify the correct format when importing from CSV or Text files

[image]

Comment: Tried this solution: taking them to another column with the Function VALUE(A2).

But it did not work.... Too many rows to edit every single value....

Even tried to copy and paste as value in another sheet and had the same problem....

Comment: See my edited answer. You have to take the spanish Version of `VALUE`, of course ...